# curl POST -o downloads a zip file but ansible does not?

Tags: ansible

I'm executing below commands -

```
JOINER_CONFIG=`curl -s -S -X GET -H "Accept: application/xml" http://dbsrd3485:8001/admin/v1/server-config`;curl -s -S --digest --user admin:NPgE3sFE -X POST -o cluster-config.zip -d "group=Default" --data-urlencode "server-config=${JOINER_CONFIG}" -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" http://dbsrd3510:8001/admin/v1/cluster-config
```

The output is `cluster-config.zip`. How can I use ansible to perform the same job. I tried below ansible command but it doesn't return the zip file -

```
ansible dbsrd3485 -m shell -a 'JOINER_CONFIG=`curl -s -S -X GET -H "Accept: application/xml" http://dbsrd3485:8001/admin/v1/server-config`;curl -s -S --digest --user admin:NPgE3sFE -X POST -o cluster-config.zip -d "group=Default" --data-urlencode "server-config=${JOINER_CONFIG}" -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" http://dbsrd3510:8001/admin/v1/cluster-config'
```

The output is -

```
dbsrd3485 | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
```

I would appreciate if you someone can provide a yml script to execute using ansible-playbook.

Comment: Ansible is running the shell command(s) on the remote host (dbsrd3485) - are you expecting to get the file downloaded on the control machine, not the remote one? (Sorry, I might be misunderstanding the question.)

Comment: @nwinkler: No that is the local host only.

Comment: Well, if you run `ansible foo -m shell -a 'curl http://example.com'`, this is going to run the `curl` command on the host `foo`, not on your local machine. Based on this, I would expect that your expected file is downloaded on the remote machine.

Comment: @nwinkler Well the host name is same from where I'm executing the command. So if it is getting downloaded then what is the path? the currect directory from where i executed the command ?

Comment: Good point, that wasn't clear from the question. Try to run Ansible with the `-vvv` parameter, which should output more log/debug messages - this should contain the directory. Or add a `pwd` command before your second `curl` command to show the current directory.

Comment: It is not clear if https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/get_url_module.html can help.